# Why does msbuild 15 not recognize the pack target, if it recognizes the restore target just fine?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, nuget

So I can restore and build just fine:

```
C:\xyz\MyApp [master ↑1]> git clean -qdfx
C:\xyz\MyApp [master ↑1]> msbuild /t:restore
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.169+g1ccb72aefa for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 11/18/2018 8:24:37 PM.
Project "C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp.sln" on node 1 (Restore target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Restore:
  Restoring packages for C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppFileTool\MyAppFileTool.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppHelper\MyAppHelper.csproj...
  Committing restore...
  Committing restore...
  Committing restore...
  Generating MSBuild file C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppFileTool\obj\MyAppFileTool.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp\obj\MyApp.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppHelper\obj\MyAppHelper.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppFileTool\obj\MyAppFileTool.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp\obj\MyApp.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppHelper\obj\MyAppHelper.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp\obj\project.assets.json
  Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppFileTool\obj\project.assets.json
  Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppHelper\obj\project.assets.json
  Restore completed in 367.2 ms for C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppHelper\MyAppHelper.csproj.
  Restore completed in 367.46 ms for C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.csproj.
  Restore completed in 367.02 ms for C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppFileTool\MyAppFileTool.csproj.

  NuGet Config files used:
      C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
      C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

  Feeds used:
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
Done Building Project "C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp.sln" (Restore target(s)).


Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.01
C:\xyz\MyApp [master ↑1]> msbuild /m /v:m
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.169+g1ccb72aefa for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  MyAppHelper -> C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppHelper\bin\Debug\MyAppHelper.dll
  MyApp -> C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe
  MyAppFileTool -> C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppFileTool\bin\Debug\MyAppFileTool.exe
```

Therefore I expect the pack target to work too, but it does not:

```
C:\xyz\MyApp [master ↑1]> msbuild /t:pack
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.169+g1ccb72aefa for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 11/18/2018 8:24:55 PM.
Project "C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp.sln" on node 1 (pack target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp.sln" (1) is building "C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppFileTool\MyAppFileTool.csproj" (2) on node 1 (pack target(s)).
C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppFileTool\MyAppFileTool.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "pack" does not exist in the project.
Done Building Project "C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppFileTool\MyAppFileTool.csproj" (pack target(s)) -- FAILED.

Project "C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp.sln" (1) is building "C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.csproj" (3) on node 1 (pack target(s)).
C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "pack" does not exist in the project.
Done Building Project "C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.csproj" (pack target(s)) -- FAILED.

Project "C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp.sln" (1) is building "C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppHelper\MyAppHelper.csproj" (4) on node 1 (pack target(s)).
C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppHelper\MyAppHelper.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "pack" does not exist in the project.
Done Building Project "C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppHelper\MyAppHelper.csproj" (pack target(s)) -- FAILED.

Done Building Project "C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp.sln" (pack target(s)) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp.sln" (pack target) (1) ->
"C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppFileTool\MyAppFileTool.csproj" (pack target) (2) ->
  C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppFileTool\MyAppFileTool.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "pack" does not exist in the project.


"C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp.sln" (pack target) (1) ->
"C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.csproj" (pack target) (3) ->
  C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "pack" does not exist in the project.


"C:\xyz\MyApp\MyApp.sln" (pack target) (1) ->
"C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppHelper\MyAppHelper.csproj" (pack target) (4) ->
  C:\xyz\MyApp\MyAppHelper\MyAppHelper.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "pack" does not exist in the project.

    0 Warning(s)
    3 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.27
C:\xyz\MyApp [master ↑1]>
```

What is wrong?

**EDIT 1**

I have just created a new .NET Standard project and there both `restore` and `pack` work fine. The solution in question is a .NET Framework 4.7.2 solution that I converted to use `PackageReference` with the help of Visual Studio 2017. I did nothing manually.

Comment: Why do I need to add msbuild community tasks? Isn't it supposed to be supported out of the box in msbuild 15? The `restore` target works, so clearly the NuGet support is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm by no means an MSBuild expert, but I believe it's more complicated than to say that NuGet is integrated with MSBuild. I don't believe that MSBuild 15 has built-in knowledge of NuGet, even the restore target, which can be confirmed by creating an empty MSBuild project file `<Project></Project>`. Run `msbuild /t:restore` and see the error message says that there is no target restore.

Therefore, the restore target is not actually built into msbuild.exe, but is actually defined in a targets file that your project is using. So, in order for a pack target to be defined, you need to import a different target file.

From a less theoretical, more practical, point of view, the "old" style csproj files (ones that import `Microsoft.Common.CSharp.targets`, or something like that) do not define the pack target, but the new SDK-style projects do.

Therefore, in order to be able to pack from msbuild, you need to migrate to SDK-style projects. Some people have a misconception that you need to target .NET Core to use SDK-style projects, which is not true. SDK style projects became available at the same time as .NET Core , and .NET Core projects need SDK-style projects, but you can still target the .NET Framework.

Comment: You are right in that "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets" does not include the `pack` target, but it sure does include the `restore` target. So, as I understand I must migrate to a new SDK style project. How?

Comment: There's no one-size-fits-all approach. If your assembly is a basic class library, I suggest creating a new .NET Core class library project, replace your project's csproj with the one from the new project template, then do what's needed to make your project build again. [Here's an old blog post](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) with some other suggestions.

Comment: I talked to my team this morning, and was told that the dotnet cli pulls in its own targets, so if you have it installed, `dotnet pack` might work, even if `msbuild /t:pack` does not. I don't have time to try it myself right now, but wanted to give another option in case it helps.

Comment: Nope, `dotnet pack` fails with the same message - target `pack` does not exist.

Comment: I am trying to migrate using a tool, maybe you can help me out here too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368555/why-am-i-unable-to-run-dotnet-tool-install-global-bla-bla-bla