# Why am I unable to run dotnet tool install --global bla-bla-bla?

Tags: windows, .net-core

Specifically, I am trying to run `dotnet tool install --global Project2015To2017.Migrate2017.Tool` as explained here - https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017#as-a-net-core-global-tool

Here is what I get:

```
c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(135,5): error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1. [C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\3sdfphfy.fq0\restore.csproj]
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'project2015to2017.migrate2017.tool' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET Core tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.
```

So, I went to https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1 and installed the .NET Core Installer x64 of SDK 2.1.500. When this did not work I installed the same for Runtime 2.1.6 (do not think it did anything). Anyway, the error message stays and I have no idea what am I expected to do.

**EDIT 1**

```
C:\xyz\MyApp [master ≡]> dotnet --list-sdks
1.0.0-preview2-003131 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.500 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

**EDIT 2**

```
C:\xyz\MyApp [master ≡]> dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.1.500
The template "global.json file" was created successfully.
C:\xyz\MyApp [master ≡ +1 ~0 -0 !]> cat .\global.json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.1.500"
  }
}
C:\xyz\MyApp [master ≡ +1 ~0 -0 !]> dotnet tool install --global Project2015To2017.Migrate2017.Tool
c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(135,5): error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1. [C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\lrfiazvp.bxe\restore.csproj]
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'project2015to2017.migrate2017.tool' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET Core tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.
C:\xyz\MyApp [master ≡ +1 ~0 -0 !]>
```

**EDIT 3**

```
C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp> dotnet --list-sdks
1.0.0-preview2-003131 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.500 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp> Test-Path global.json
False
C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp> cd ..
C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local> Test-Path global.json
False
C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local> cd ..
C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData> Test-Path global.json
False
C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData> cd ..
C:\Users\mkharitonov> Test-Path global.json
False
C:\Users\mkharitonov> cd ..
C:\Users> Test-Path global.json
False
C:\Users> cd ..
C:\> Test-Path global.json
False
C:\>
```

Comment: Maybe you have a `global.json` in your path that is defaulting to an older SDK. Can you try [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json#globaljson-and-the-net-core-cli) to create a local one and try the install again?

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 1**. Is it OK?

Comment: Can you run 'dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.1.500' in your local folder and then run the 'dotnet tool ...' command again and see if it works?

Comment: Same bad result.

Comment: After you add the `global.json` file, what does `dotnet --version` in that directory say?

Comment: @omajid - 2.1.500

Comment: Hm. Do you have a `globa.json` in `C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\lrfiazvp.bxe\` or in any parent directory up to `C:\`?

Comment: The `lrfiazvp.bxe`  folder does not exist. Looks like it is a temp folder created and cleared each time. But I checked the rest - **EDIT 3**

Answer (score 3):

You can run **dotnet tool install** with diagnostic verbosity level.
For example:

```
dotnet tool install --global Project2015To2017.Migrate2017.Tool -v diag
```

I had some problem and in my case I had error:

```
The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found
```

To solve this problem I changed environment variable **MSBuildSDKsPath** (advice from https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2532)